# Upgrade to strong params causing create action to throw mass assignment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am upgrading my Rails app from Rails 3.2.8 to Rails 4.0.0 following RailsCast #415 (http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4?view=asciicast) and all is good until I upgrade to strong parameters.  After updating the Events controller to use strong parameters I'm able to submit a form to create a new Event (no validation errors are thrown) but all the submitted params are null and the terminal log (running locally) says,

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Event: street, description, host_name, event_date(1i), event_date(2i), event_date(3i), event_time(1i), event_time(2i), event_time(3i), event_time(4i), event_time(5i), event_name, end_time(1i), end_time(2i), end_time(3i), end_time(4i), end_time(5i)
```

so obviously I am having a mass assignment problem and the strong parameters are not working properly.

The Events controller has the following private method:

```
private
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:city, :state, :street, :zip, :description,
        :host_name, :host_contact, :event_date, :event_time,
        :instructions, :event_name, :end_time)
  end
```

And the event#create action looks like (created with a scaffold):

```
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The gemfile has the following gem included for use during the transition:
    gem 'protected_attributes'

and the application.rb file has whitelist_attributes set to false (it's commented out):

```
# config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

Any help in what I'm missing to connect the dots here would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Having "gem 'protected_attributes'" in my gemfile was causing a conflict with redefined methods.  Removed it and all was good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having "gem 'protected_attributes'" in my gemfile was causing a conflict with redefined methods. Removed it and all was good.